# How to use or implement RefreshView in dotnet MAUI with Blazor

Tags: maui, maui-blazor

I am building both a web app and a mobile app with Blazor.  I am sharing some components and functionality between the AspNetCore project for web and the .NET MAUI project for my app.
It seems to work quite nice so far, but I want to leverage the `RefreshView` component that is available in .NET MAUI.  However, that component only seems to work in XAML, and I don't seem to find a way how to incorporate that (or a similar behavior) in my blazor based MAUI app.

Would someone have an idea on how to do that?

Best regards

Comment: Need more info about what you are trying to do. You can make a Maui layout that includes a RefreshView AND also includes a BlazorWebView, but these are still separate UI elements. You can't put a RefreshView *inside* of a BlazorWebView. Some layouts are capable of OVERLAYING elements, which might help you. See docs for Grid, AbsoluteLayout, RelativeLayout. The BlazorWebView won't be aware of the location and bounds of other Maui elements, though there may be ways to programmatically send that information to the BlazorWebView.

Comment: it seems the answer to this question (that was answered yesterday) does indeed what you describe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69696776/net-maui-xaml-inside-blazorwebview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shortly after this question was asked, an old question got answered that described the approach that I now have successfully taken.

[.NET MAUI Xaml inside BlazorWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69696776/net-maui-xaml-inside-blazorwebview/)